# Rotate the profile photo in mobile version

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using laravel jetstream with livewire and enabled Features::profilePhotos().

When I upload a profile picture from the computer, it displays and saves it correctly but if I upload it from the mobile it rotates the picture.

livewire already has a trait to display the image temporarily before saving it:

```
@if ($photo)
Photo Preview:
<img src="{{ $photo->temporaryUrl() `}}">
@endif
```

The first thing is that I don't know how I can intervene before the temporary photo is displayed in order to orientate it correctly.
I have tried with intervation image in this way but it doesn't work:

```
public function updatedPhoto()
    {
        Image::make($this->photo)->orientate();
    }
```

When saving the image I have also tried with intervention image but it does not orientate it correctly either.

```
public function update()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user->id)],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'image', 'max:1024'],
        ]);

        // Guardamos en User
        $this->user->forceFill([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ])->save();

        // Guardamos en Profile
        if($this->url || $this->biography){
            $this->user->profile()->updateOrCreate(
                [ 'user_id' => $this->user->id],
                ['url' => $this->url, 'biography' => $this->biography,]
                );
        }
        // Si tiene foto
        if (isset($this->photo)) {

            // Si existe directorio, se borra
            if (!file_exists("profile_images/{$this->user->slug}")) {
                Storage::deleteDirectory("profile_images/{$this->user->slug}");
                //     mkdir("storage/thumbs/profile-photos/", 666, true);
                }


            //get file extension
            $extension = $this->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //filename to store
            $filenametostore = $this->user->slug.'.'.$extension;

            //Upload File
            $thumb = $this->photo->storeAs("profile_images/{$this->user->slug}/thumbnail", $filenametostore);
            $medium = $this->photo->storeAs("profile_images/{$this->user->slug}/medium", $filenametostore);
            $large = $this->photo->storeAs("profile_images/{$this->user->slug}/large", $filenametostore);

            // RESIZE + FIT - THUMB
            $img = Image::make( public_path('storage/'.$thumb))->fit(40);
            $img->orientate();
            $img->save();

            // RESIZE + FIT - MEDIUM
            $img = Image::make( public_path('storage/'.$medium))->fit(126);
            $img->orientate();
            $img->save();

            // RESIZE + FIT - large
            $img = Image::make( public_path('storage/'.$large))->fit(400);
            $img->orientate();
            $img->save();

            $this->user->profile()->updateOrCreate(
                ['user_id' => $this->user->id ],
                [
                    'img_thumb' => "storage/profile_images/{$this->user->slug}/thumbnail/$filenametostore",
                    'img_medium' => "storage/profile_images/{$this->user->slug}/medium/$filenametostore",
                    'img_large' => "storage/profile_images/{$this->user->slug}/large/$filenametostore",
                ]
            );

            session()->flash('message',  'Tu foto se ha guardado correctamente');

        }
```

This only happens in production and when I enter with the mobile, if I enter from the computer it does it correctly.

Any help?

Comment: What do you expect `orientate` to do? Should it always use landscape or use the original orientation(landscape or portrait) the image was taken with?

Comment: According to what I read, the problem is that the images captured with the mobile phone are not displayed correctly depending on the orientation. This method reads the EXIF image profile setting 'Orientation' and performs a rotation on the image to display the image correctly. But maybe I'm wrong. I am not an expert on this

Comment: What is "correctly"? That it matches the orientation it was originally taking in?

Comment: If I capture the image vertically, then when I upload it, it shows it as it is, the same if the photo is horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = Image::make($file)->orientate();
            $exif = exif_read_data($foto);
            if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
                switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                    case 8:
                        $img->rotate(90);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $img->rotate(180);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $img->rotate(-90);
                        break;
                }
            }
        // if ($img->width() > $img->height()) {
            // $img->rotate(270);
        // }
        $img->resize(null, 1000, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        return $img->save($destination.'/'.$namefile);
```